# How to set charging cap for a laptop battery?

Tags: laptop, battery-life

From various sources I learned that when you need store a battery for extended period of time, it's best to support it's charge level somewhere around 40-50%. Some laptops have firmware settings which allow to set the charge cap, so it looks like a best solution to keep it plugged with this settings on when you need to store it for some extended period (like a year or so).

However most old models do not have such option, and I wonder if there are any tricks/devices or whatever I can leverage to maintain partially charged battery for months or years on such models?

Comment: If you own a Lenovo laptop, there exists an application called “Lenovo Vantage” that will allow you to do this very easily.